# How to use controls inside repeater control in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, insert, repeater

Here is my C# code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        int id;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label2.Text = " " + Session["username"] + " ";
            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Prod_Id"].ToString());
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from Product  where Prod_Id="+ id +"";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
                Repeater1.DataBind();
                con.Close();

            }
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into Order values('" + Label2.Text + "','"+ Label3.Text +"')";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }

    }

here is my.aspx code

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/welcome_mstr.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="desc.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">



&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <b>Welcome</b>



<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;!<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
        onitemcommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
<HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>

       <div style=" width:700px; margin-left:200px; background-color:#FCFBE3">

       <br />

       <table>

       <tr><td><img alt="" src='<%# Eval("Image") %>' style=" width:299px; height:299px;" /></td>


        <td valign="top"><table >
        <tr><td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Prod_Name") %>'></asp:Label></td></tr>


        <tr><td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Weight") %>'></asp:Label></td></tr>


       <tr><td align="left">Cost: ₹<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Price") %>'></asp:Label></td></tr>
       <tr><td>
           <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Order" /> </td></tr>
       </table>
       </td>
       </tr>

       </table>
       </div>



        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

</asp:Content>
```

I want to use the `Text` property of a control inside the Repeater control and insert that text value into a table through a button click event, but I am not able to access the control itself. It shows an error like this:

> The name 'label3' does not exist in the current context

How could I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `label3.` your code would not compile.

Comment: @AfnanAhmad Label3.Text

Comment: Major improvements + Title

Comment: anyone got any idea where those &nbsp; are coming from

Answer (score 1):

You can access it like the following snippet:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strLabel3 = string.Empty;
    foreach (RepeaterItem ri in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        Label lbl3= (Label)ri.FindControl("Label3");
        strLabel3 = lbl3.Text;
    }

    //Remaing logic
}
```

***UPDATE 1***

You can do it like this also:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button) sender;
    RepeaterItem item = (RepeaterItem) btn.NamingContainer;
    Label lbl3 = (Label)item.FindControl("Label3");
    string strlbl3 = lbl3.Text;
}
```

Comment: @Shaikh Usama still you are not able to access it ?

Comment: I am getting the same error "The name 'label3' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: You have not defined `Button1_Click` in your markup even.

Comment: It is `Label3` not `label3`

Comment: I have used Label3.Text only. Please help.

Comment: I have inserted your updated snippet also then too the same error persist !     I have inserted it above 'String CS'.

Comment: Are you sue Label3 exists in your markup ? Please check spellings.

Comment: I am 110% sure.

Comment: This should work than. You need to dig into matter whats going wrong at your side. Its working fine.

Comment: "you have not defined Button1_Click in your markup even". what do you mean by this?

Comment: In your provided markup it is `<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Order" />` where is `OnClick="Button1_Click"` ?